# when service opens an activity, second instance of app creates

Tags: android, android-intent, service, notifications, android-activity

im working on app that require launch app from a service.
my problem is service create new instance of app Although my app is not closed. i want just one instance.
i find this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043671/notification-click-activity-already-open) like my problem but i can't use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT`
cause my apps crashes.

i change my tabactivity(main activity) to

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

but problem still remains. 
would some one guid me. thank you very much

this is my service:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


    public class MyAlarmService extends Service {

         @Override
            public void onCreate() {


            }



            @Override
            public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
                return null;

            }



            @Override
            public void onDestroy() {

                super.onDestroy();


            }



            @Override
            public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
                super.onStart(intent, startId);
                openActivity(AlertActivity.class);
                Log.i("LOG", "service started");

            }



            @Override
            public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
                return super.onUnbind(intent);

            }



            public void openActivity(Class activity) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), activity);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);

            }
    }
```

and this is my manifest:

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/drink1"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:name=".G"
        >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".MainTabActivity" 
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            <!-- it cause to just one instance of app be exist -->

            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".AlertActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">


        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DrinkoflifeActivity"
            ></activity>

        <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity">


        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".StaticActivity">

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".ContactUsActivity"></activity>
       <activity android:name="org.achartengine.GraphicalActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".DataActivity">


        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LogoActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">


        </activity>

        <service android:name=".MyAlarmService" />

    </application>
```

Comment: Why are you calling `AlertActivity` and not `MainTabActivity`?

Comment: @Geralt: alert activity is a some kind off alarm animation form that lead to main activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `launchMode="singleTop"` on your `MainActivity` is probably not necessary and isn't going to help you here.

When your service starts `AlertActivity`, it will create a new instance of that activity. If your application has an active task, this will also result in the active task being brought to the foreground and the new instance of `AlertActivity` will be created on top of any other activities in the task. In a comment you wrote that `AlertActivity` leads to `MainActivity` then the problem is in how you are starting the `MainActivity` from the `AlertActivity`.

You should probably start the `MainActivity` from the `AlertActivity` this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Assuming that the `MainActivity` is the root activity in the task and there is still an active instance (ie: it has not yet been finished), this code will remove any other activities from the task stack and go back to the existing instance of `MainActivity`.