# notification on lock/home button press, on click back to tab fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, notifications, statusbar, android-notifications

once again.... I'm following this tutorial [androidhive tab layout with swipe able views](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/)... I have the tab layout in one of the sub activities. The MainActivity is a list view where clicking on one of the items in the list view, it opens up the tab layout/activity. In the last tab, i have a count down timer of 20 seconds, users have to lock their phone or press the home button to do a notification (at the status bar) demo. As the tab is a fragment, how do I reopen the app by tapping on the notification at the status bar to bring them back to the third tab/fragment?

I have been searching but none of the answer seems to be what i am looking for. I hope someone out there do guide me along as I want to learn more. Thank you!

Comment: put information in the intent bundle

Comment: @tyczj could you elaborate a little more, please? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043671/notification-click-activity-already-open/12043699#12043699) and this [sample notification tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.sg/2012/05/generate-notification-using.html), I was able to get what I want. All it needed was to set singleTop to the activity in manifest if you don't want the activity to be called twice.