# Re-Opening activity from Service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

I'm working on android app that lets users switch to google navigation.
I've been asked to get users a solution to get back to the app without scrolling through list of open apps. I found the way to draw a button on top of everything but am struggling to get nice flow with activity life-cycle.

If user gets back to the app through manually selecting my app in list of existing apps - my app starts with onResume, 
However if i force my app to get back via service button it is starting with onCreate and all unsaved data i had withing my activity is getting lost.

This is the code i use to call activity back via service and button

```
  Intent myIntent = new Intent ( getApplicationContext(), PhoneView.class );
                    myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
                    getApplicationContext().startActivity(myIntent);
```

I think i can putExtra bool in this call from Service and before i let user off my activity - i can save all the fields and recreate it back, but it feels like to much of extra work..

Is there a way to call my app from service and have it use existing activity, rather than to go through onCreate again assuming i know that my activity is running?

Comment: Check out this, it might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305088/how-to-make-notification-intent-resume-rather-than-making-a-new-intent

Comment: Thank you Eric, i think i just fond my answer here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043671/notification-click-activity-already-open
All you have to do is to add 1 line to activity in manifest file
            android:launchMode="singleTop"

Comment: Nice, I'll keep that in mind for my own apps.