# How to run activity in background?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

How to run chat activity in background to show message notification,and also tell when chat activity is in foreground then it doesn't show any notification

Answer (score 0):

When you want to do something in the background,you can use a AsyncTask.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

You should user android [NotificationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html) for that purpose.

And chech this post [Notification Click: Activity Already Open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043671/notification-click-activity-already-open)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fine piece of document containing sample code with notifications manager
[on Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Also AsyncTask is not suited for long running operations as your async service will be killed off with your app where foreground service can live past that.