# need to open multiple notification in one activity

Tags: android, push-notification, android-push-notification

I have implemented push notifications for my android app .I am able to show multiple notification in notification bar but only one notification work at a time.

**i think the problem in flags type**

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
```

and

```
PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
```

this is my **code** , please tell me what type of Flag i will set

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
final PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
PendingIntent.getActivity(
   mContext,
   0,
   intent,
   PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
);
```

Comment: what have you done for show notification?

Comment: Please show your Notification Manager code, it's problem

Comment: Also Read [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043671/notification-click-activity-already-open).

Comment: did my solution work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the different ID for each notification. as follows : 
   (put different notification ID every time).

You can also create unique notification ID each time by following :

```
int notiID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

PendingIntent.getActivity(
   mContext,
   notiID, //notification ID
   intent,
   0
);
```

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm trying:
`
int NOTIFICATION_ID = (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        final PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        mContext,
                        NOTIFICATION_ID,
                        intent,
                        0
                );
`

but all notification bar has clear

Comment: did you tried this code : int notiID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();   ??

Comment: yes but all notifications bar has been closed, send me your email, can i send you my **NotificationUtils** Class